# Read response outputstream in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, axios, blob

I have a response in this given format in java:

```
if (Files.exists(filePath)) {
        response.setContentType(Files.probeContentType(filePath));
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName());
        Files.copy(filePath, response.getOutputStream());
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
      }
```

How do I read the file and download in javascript react?

```
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', response.filename);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
```

But its not working,How can I fix it and read file name and data and download it on get request?